# How to make div take all vertical space whetever footer exist or not

Tags: html, css

I want to make content div to be more flexible. The .content div took all available place. But i want to make it work in case of footer may doesn't exist. So, how to make contant take all available place whatever footer exist or not? (the size of container is fixed)

Look at example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5374/

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">Header</div>

    <div class="content">
 content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The only thing you want to fix is that if you remove content that is below .content, .content should fill out that spot? I am getting confused with the overflow and stuff you have added and loses focus on the actual question.

Comment: @thommyjonasson yep, I just want make .content fill footer part too, of footer removed

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this: http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5381/

What I don't understand though is why you would like the `.content` to fill out more space? Doesn't it look ugly if the `.content` takes up more space without any real content in it? The problem with the solution you want it to be, is that I don't think it can be done using CSS only. The reason for this is that there is no way to check if some content doesn't exist. Going to check into this abit further, but I am sceptical.

Comment: No, I just want to make content to take all available space. Your footer is just attached to bottom so content won't use it space if footer doesn't exist

Comment: Well, the way to probably accomplish this is to set the .footer to {position:absolute; bottom:0;} and in .content{padding:0 0 20px 0;}. Something like that, but I would never consider doing it. Either you have a footer or you don't :)